# How to show Video without stopping even if orientation changed in Android

Tags: performance, android-layout

I am calling a web service to load video content, and displaying video in webview . 
But when i change the orientation then the webservice is Reloading/called again , as activity is calling its oncreate() method.

For this i have used in manifest.xml file :

```
 <activity android:name="ChallengeViewdefinition"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">           </activity>
```

**My Requirement:**

> *if in Portrait mode:* I want Some Header and one EditText above the VideoView.
>
> If in Landscape Mode:  I want VideoView in full screen.(Want to hide edittext and header)

please suggest me.

Comment: Almost Like Youtube Application video display.